# How to become a tor guard node?

Tags: guard-node

From a little bit of research, I found that anyone can be any node other than a guard node. Why is that so? On some forums they say stable uptime for a few weeks is required, but is there a minimum requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Tor article, [The lifecycle of a new relay](https://blog.torproject.org/lifecycle-new-relay) We see that a relay node could become eligible as soon as 8 days after it has been created but in reality it needs to show a longer term history of good uptime and available bandwidth.

Here is the [spec sheet](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/dir-spec.txt#n1913). There appears to be at least two flags that must be set to become a guard:

```
 "guard-wfu" -- WFU (in seconds) required for a relay to be
                marked as guard.

 "guard-tk" -- Weighted Time Known (in seconds) required for a
               relay to be marked as guard.
```

However nowhere that I can see are the actual metrics discussed for achieving these two flags.